# Trying to match array index pattern in string using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I'm using regex to get the indices of variables accessing pattern represented as string, for example:

```
string = "test[2][56].var1[4]"
```

The regex match result in the groups 2, 56, 4 captured.

```
matchGroups = ["2", "56", "4"]
```

The regex below works.

`\[([^\.\]]+)\]`

But I can't allow cases like:

`"test.[3].var1"`
or
`"test[3]/"`

I tried to limit the characters allowed before and after each group using the regex below:

`[\]a-zA-Z0-9]\[([^\.\]]+)\]([\[a-zA-Z0-9])?`

But some cases stopped working like the case  `"test[0].var7[3][4]"`(4 is not captured).

I need help to make this work with all cases again(cases are in the link below).

https://regex101.com/r/mOgOHn/2

Comment: *"But I can't allow cases like ... `"test[3]/"`"*: that puzzles me. So the `/` should make it not match? Which other characters should make it not match? What if `"test[3][4]/"`? Does then the `[3]` still match, but not the `[4]`? What about a space, a line break, a comma instead of the slash....etc?  What should match in `"test[1][hello][2][#][3], next[4]"`?

Comment: Sorry @trincot I didn't specified it, but the text input should be a valid javascript array access pattern, `test[3][4]/` is not valid in javascript for example.

Comment: So would you match `test[foo[3]]` and `test["foo"]` and `test[4/2]`?

Comment: Thank you for asking these questions I didn't clarify well, I should allow only numeric indexes like `test[4]`, not expressions or object property, I also can't allow `test[foo[3]]`, I didn't think about this case, I should avoid it too.

Comment: So if there is a mix of those, do you still want to match the numeric indexes, or should nothing match? Like for `test[1].view[2]["foo"][3][4/2]` should it match 1, 2 and 3, or should it match nothing? What if there is a semicolon after this expression, like `test[1].view[2]["foo"][3][4/2];` ... should it then match nothing?

Comment: Why would you do this anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would `replace` the string, then do *matching*

### Replace Regex:

```
/.*?\[(\d+)\].*?/
```

**Replace the string** where any number between brackets is replaced by a number followed by `,`

### Match Regex:

```
/\d+(?=,)/
```

**Look ahead positive**; which
Find any number followed by `,`

```js
const captureNumber = str => str.replace(/.*?\[(\d+)\].*?/g, "$1,").match(/\d+(?=,)/g)

console.log(captureNumber("test[0].var7[3][4]")); //[ "0", "3", "4" ]
console.log(captureNumber("test[3]/")); //[ "3" ] 
console.log(captureNumber("test.[3].var1")); //[ "3" ] 
console.log(captureNumber("test[2][56].var1[4]")); //[ "2", "56", "4" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest would be to use a regexp using a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead.
To this, you can add safety on spaces in case you have a case like "test[ 2 ][ 56  ].var1[ 4 ]", to which a .trim() method string must be applied.
Here is a snippet illustrating this:

```js
const getIndex = str => str.match(/(?<=\[) *\d+ *(?=\])/g).map(val => val.trim());

console.log(getIndex("test[0].var7[3][4]")); //[ "0", "3", "4" ]
console.log(getIndex("test[3]/")); //[ "3" ]
console.log(getIndex("test.[3].var1")); //[ "3" ]
console.log(getIndex("test[2 ][   56   ].var1[4 ]")); //[ "2", "56", "4" ]
```

Good luck !